Snapshot replication taking too long for large database using SQL Server Management Studio
I have a 70 GB loaded SQL database and need to perform snapshot replication. I created the publisher and started the snapshot agent, but it takes very long Even after 5 hours, the process did not generate an unc snapshort. Then I removed the publisher and started searching for a new way, Here is one URL with an answer to take a backup and restore it to the subscriber machine, then run the script. But should I follow the 11-year-old answer on the URL below? Or do you have any other ideas?
Snapshot for transactional replication taking too long for large database
Note: Subscriber is on another machine and I will do tomorrow this above url process but need your more suggestion.

Snapshot replication has not changed, that's still a valid approach.

70 GB isn't a huge amount of data. 5 hours sounds much longer than should be needed for data of that size. Are you sure it isn't running into an error while running?...anything reported in the Replication Monitor? How many rows in total are being replicated, roughly?
